# Check value exists or not before wriring it into textfile php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am adding username and userid into a text file `onload` of a page as follows:

```
$.post("addusersonload.php", {userid:chatusrid,username:chatusrname}, function (data) { 

  });
```

**addusersonload.php**

```
$name = $_REQUEST['username'];
$usrid = $_REQUEST['userid'];

fwrite(fopen('addusersonload.txt', 'a'), "$usrid,$name\n");
```

I am getting the value in text field as follows:

```
UserA, 1
UserB, 2
UserA, 1
UserB, 2
```

I want to check the textfile that the same value exists or not before writing into it.so that the duplication will not occur!!

Comment: why not use database instead of text file ?

Comment: Not feasible tried before. because of load I have changed logic!!

Comment: use database , if not available use json even ..

Comment: Well in that case you have to read through all the text file and compare the new name and userid each time you try to add something.

Comment: _Not feasible tried before. because of load I have changed logic_ So what about the load on your file system caused by all the reading and checking you are going to have to do.

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you suggest any other alternative? without using database

Comment: There are no other alternatives, why is using a database causing an overload? What overload is it causing? Could this overload be due to you doing something _wrong_ or _badly_ Show us that code and we can make suggestions on improvements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a DB is the best option for what you need, but, if you really need to write to a file, you can use:

```
if(!empty($_POST['username']) and !empty($_POST['userid'])){
    $log_file = "sum_file.txt";
    $logContent = file_get_contents("sum_file.txt");

    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $userId = $_POST['userid'];

    if (!preg_match("/($user),\\s+($userId)\$/m", $logContent)) {
        file_put_contents($log_file, "$user, $userId", FILE_APPEND);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally  recommend you to use db , but still i may help you .. You should use json for this

```
function writeToFile($filename, $msg)
 { 
   $msgArray=array();
   if(file_exists($filename))
        {
        $arrMsg=json_decode(file_get_contents($filename),true);
        if($msg['userId']==$arrmsg['userId'])
              die('already there'); //checking done
        foreach ($arrMsg as $ob)
          {
             array_push($msgArray,$ob);
          }
        unlink($filename);
        }
   array_push($msgArray,$msg);
   $msgArrayJSON=json_encode($msgArray);
   // open file
   $fd = fopen($filename, "a");
   // write string
   fwrite($fd, $msgArrayJSON. PHP_EOL);
   // close file
   fclose($fd);
}
```

And by using the above function you may add user like

```
writeToFile('user.json', array("userId"=>$id,"userName"=>$name));
```

Finally , you could get users from file as below

```
$user_array=json_decode(file_get_contents('user.json'),true);
```

Comment: And what happens when he get 100,000 users? Do you think this is going to be a solution that will run quickly? Do you think this file will fit nicely in memory? Do you have any idea what happens when somone accidentlly deletes this file?

Comment: No of course not , but this is just an alternative approach (even not recommended by me), as per need of @@OP